# Target bounding box coordinates for classic YOLOv2

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

Let's say I build training data for classic YOLOv2 from paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf let me know if I understand output format correctly.

Example Bounding box from picture:

- bounding box: {class: 2, confidence: 1, x: 0.698, y: 0.667, h: 0.145, w: 0.084, grid_cell: (9, 8)}

Data settings:

- grid size: 13x13
- classes: 4
- anchor boxes: 5. My bounding box is closest to: {'w': 0.0559, 'h': 0.0954}.

x, y, w and h are normalized in regards to whole image.

Th paper says that:

> Instead of predicting offsets we follow the approach of
> YOLO and predict location coordinates relative to the location of the grid cell. This bounds the ground truth to fall
> between 0 and 1.

and:
[image]

Moreover to go from x, y, w, h to t(x), t(y), t(w) and t(h) I need revert this equations:
[image]
`t(x) = x - cx = 0.698 - 9/13 = 0.0056`
`t(y) = y - cy = 0.667 - 8/13 = 0.0516`
`t(w) = ln(bw / pw) = ln(0.084 / 0.0559) = 0.4072`
`t(h) = ln(bh / ph) = ln(0.145 / 0.0954) = 0.4186`

Fianlly does it mean that my target array looks like:
total output shape `OUTPUT = 13 x 13 x 5[anchors] * (5[bbox_details] + 4[classes])`
this bounding box will be assigned in `OUTPUT[9, 8, 9:18] = BBOX_ARRAY`

`BBOX_ARRAY = [1, 0.0056, 0.0516, 0.4072, 0.4186] + [0, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: btw. I know that ultralytics/darknet simplifies the whole process but in this example I'm building the entire architecture from scratch for learning purpose.